# Pygame help - TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not pygame.Surface

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm following along with the tutorial here...
http://pyvideo.org/video/1718/introduction-to-pygame

I ran into the traceback at the bottom and couldn't seem to figure out where to start looking for a problem...it turns out there's one line of code in the slides that isn't included in the + and - bits, showing what he's added/removed at each step, so when it was supposed to be added is unclear. I used Pycharms debugger to step through and figure out that it was that one line that was the problem, and now it's commented out.

I'm confused as to why that line was there, I can't seem to find the code examples he had prepared to see what else I'm missing (I didn't hear any complaints from the audience in the video).

What's going on here?

```
import pygame    

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Mugger Space Cadet.jpg')
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((16, 32), self.image.get_size())

    def update(self, dt, game):
        last = self.rect.copy()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 150 * dt
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 150 * dt
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= 150 * dt
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += 150 * dt

        for cell in pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, game.walls, False):
            self.rect = last

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        background = pygame.image.load('mockup level.png')
        sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
#       sprites.add(background)
        self.player = Player(sprites)
        self.walls = pygame.sprite.Group()
        block = pygame.image.load('block.png')
        for x in range(0, 448, 32):
            for y in range(0, 320, 32):
                if x in (0, 448-32) or y in (0, 320-32):
                    wall = pygame.sprite.Sprite(self.walls)
                    wall.image = block
                    wall.rect= pygame.rect.Rect((x, y), block.get_size())
        sprites.add(self.walls)

        while True:
            dt = clock.tick(30)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return

            sprites.update(dt / 1000., self)
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            sprites.draw(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((448, 320))
    Game().main(screen)
```

And the traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 365, in add
self.add(*sprite)
TypeError: add() argument after * must be a sequence, not pygame.Surface

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jacob/PycharmProjects/PygamePractice/main.py", line 92, in <module>
    Game().main(screen)
  File "C:/Users/Jacob/PycharmProjects/PygamePractice/main.py", line 62, in main
    sprites.add(background)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 378, in add
    sprite.add_internal(self)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'add_internal'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you try to use a * operator on a function call with a Pygame.sprite.Sprite object, but you can only use it with iterable objects (list, tuple).

E.g.:

```
# define a list or tuple of arguments:
arguments = ["foo", "bar"] # or ("foo", "bar)
# The * operator will pass every item of it as own argument:
my_function(*arguments)
```

But you can't write

```
# initialize a non-iterable class:
arguments = object()
# The * operator can't split an object into multiple arguments, so an error is raised
my_function(*arguments)
```